# Open all log files in directory and sub directory in one command

Tags: command-line, bash, vim

I have directory `~/temp` with log files. This directory contains another directory `~/temp/aaa` that also contains several logs. I would like to open all log files at once. I do

```
vim -p *
```

It opens files in current directory and that is fine, but it also opens directory `aaa` with list of files in content ant I would like to omit it. 
Also no files are opened in `aaa` directory. I could add `/aaa/*` into command, but his is not good since directory name might change and I would like to have more universal command.

How to enumerate all files in directory and sub directory for `vim`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command which will open `vim` with tab for each file under the current directory:

```
vim -p `find -L . -type f -print`
```

Or the following command which will open all files in the current directory, and all files in all first-level-of-sub-directories of the current directory

```
vim -p ./* ./*/*
```

The above command is based on running `vim -p` together with example from similar answer which can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149355/how-do-i-open-all-files-in-the-current-directory-and-all-subdirectories-using-vi)

---

A few (modified) examples from [the extended answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149355/how-do-i-open-all-files-in-the-current-directory-and-all-subdirectories-using-vi) will open vim for every file under the current directory, and once `vim` will be closed, will open `vim` again for the next file, etc:

```
find . -xtype f -exec vim {} \;
```

Or

```
find -L . -type f -exec vim {} \;
```

Comment: Is that `globstar` and `extglob` in the last one? If so you should mention how to enable those options.

Comment: If your file names have spaces or special characters IIRC that find command needs altering, look at `print0` flag, and possibly needs `xargs`.

Comment: @pbhj - Thanks for your comment, which is correct for the `vim -p \`find xxx -print\` ` command! **Note that:** the two examples with `find xxx -exec vim {} \l;` works well even with filenames which includes spaces.